# Isomorphic or Equal in Vect?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

In the category of vector spaces, how many elements are there in the isomorphism class of 1-dimensional vector spaces? Secondly, is the polynomial algebra generated by the symbol $x$ equal to the polynomial algebra generated by the symbol $y$, or merely isomorphic to it.

Comment: Recall that all 1-dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$ is isomorphic to $F$ itself.

Comment: [Please do not post multiple questions in one post.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one) If you have two questions, ask two different questions, especially when they're unrelated like that.

Comment: For your first question, try to think first about the following question: "How many sets are there that have one element?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question can have no answer. Vector spaces over a given field (even $1$-dimensioanl vector spaces) are *not* a set, unless you consider a small category. It is for the same reason as the set of all sets does not exist.

For the second question, the answer is ‘yes: two polynomial algebras in one indeterminate over a given field $F$ are isomorphic’, since they are all realisations of the free algebra on one element. But they're not equal because the symbol $x$ (in general) does not belong to $F[y]$ and *vice-versa*.

Comment: @Najib What is the precise reason that they are not equal?

Comment: @Edward Because they are not even equal as sets. "The symbol $x$" is not equal to "the symbol $y$", and so however you choose to build "the polynomial algebra on the symbol $x$", it won't be equal to "the polynomial algebra on the symbol $y$". Did you read the two comments I made under your question?

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: I followed your suggestion. Does it answer better to the O.p.'s question now, in your opinion?

Comment: I think that clears it up, thanks you so much for your help.